# Validação de formulário com Js

Tags: formulário, validação

Estou trabalhando em um formulário a algum tempo, após validá-lo encontrei um erro pois não consigo submitar para trocar de pagina,além do que após o concerto de todos os erros na validação o erro de senha costuma permanecer. Também queria uma dica de como eu poderia salvar a validação em um Local Storage.

```js
 
 // pega o botão...e o input 
 var botao  = document.querySelector(".botao_cadastro");
 botao.addEventListener("click", function (){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    
    var form = document.querySelector("#cadastro_todo")
    var user   = takeUser(form) 
    var erros  = vrUser(user);
    
    if (erros.length){
        errorMessage(erros)
        vrUser.innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
});
 
// pega usuário do formulario
function takeUser(form){
    var user =  {
        FirstName : form.FirstName.value,
        LastName : form.LastName.value,
        Email : form.Email.value,
        Password : form.Password.value,
        Cpassword : form.Cpassword.value,
    }
    return user;
}

//exibe a messagem de erro
function errorMessage(erros){
    var ul = document.querySelector("#mensagem_erro")
    ul.innerHTML = "";
    erros.forEach(function(erros) {
        var li =  document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = "";
        li.textContent = erros;
        ul.appendChild(li)
    });
}

// verifica o  usuario e mostra o erro
function  vrUser(user){
    var  erros  =[]
    if(user.FirstName.length == 0)erros.push("o nome não pode ser em branco");
    if(user.LastName.length == 0)erros.push("O sobrenome não pode ser em branco");
    if(user.Email.length == 0)erros.push("o email não pode ser em branco");
    if(user.Email.indexOf("@") == -1 )erros.push("o email está inválido");
    if(user.Password.length == 0)erros.push("a senha não pode ser em branco");
    if(user.Cpassword.length == 0)erros.push(" A confirmação da senha não pode estar em branco");
    if(user.Password.length <= 5)erros.push(" a senha pode possuir  no minimo 5 caracteres");
    if(user.Password != user.Cpassword)erros.push(" as senhas não coicidem");
    
    return erros;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cadastro_todo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <title>Sistema de Cadastro</title>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id = "system" >
        <h1>Sign Up</h1> 
        <form name="form" id="cadastro_todo" action="fomr2.html"  >
           <span>Primeiro Nome:</span> <input class = "cadastro_input" type="text" name="FirstName"></p>
           <span> Sobrenome: </span> <input  class = "cadastro_input" type="text" name="LastName"></p>
           <span> Email:     </span> <input  class = "cadastro_input" type="text"  name="Email" > </p>
           <span>Senha:  </span> <input  class = "cadastro_input" type="password" name = "Password"></p>
           <span>Confirme a Senha</span> <input  class="cadastro_input" type="password" name =  "Cpassword" ></p>
            <p><input type = "button" value="Confirmar" class="botao_cadastro" >  </p>
        </form>
        <ul id = "mensagem_erro" ></ul>
    </div>



    
    <script src="js/errorreport.js" ></script>    
    <script src="js/report.js" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```